# Multiline textbox - spaces added to beginning on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I have a `Textbox` added to an `.ascx` control page as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="500" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox>
```

And it would show something like this when first loaded (4 spaces at the start included):

```
    Description goes here
```

Put simply, it's a `Multiline Textbox` with 2 lines. However, whenever we do a `Postback` to the server, when the page reloads, we get this:

```
        Description goes here
```

Another `Postback`.

```
            Description goes here
```

And so on. Basically, every time the page is refreshed after a `Postback`, it adds 4 spaces to the start of the textbox. On some pages, this isn't an issue, however, if the user is entering a fair bit of data into a `Gridview` or some other `Control`, the contents of the `Textbox` can end up shunted 20 or so characters to the right, sometimes out of the bounds of the `Textbox`.

Put simply, this is an issue for our company, as it is occurring across all of our pages. One of our clients has several times made a pass "...and could you do something about the spaces at the beginning of the textboxes at some point?"

Now, a temporary fix we have employed is the following code in our `PageLoad` function, however, we are still left with 4 spaces at the beginning of the `Textbox`. And rolling it out across 100's of `.ascx` and `.aspx` controls/pages isn't really a solution.

```
if (IsPostBack)
     txtDescription.Text = txtDescription.Text;
```

Now the big question is, does anyone know how to remove these mysterious 4 spaces that keep getting added to the start of a `Multiline Textbox`?

Comment: Besides the hack you noted at the end, how are you normally populating the text of this text box?

Comment: From where you are putting values in this textbox?

Comment: You can remove the spaces using the Trim function but I would find where the spaces are coming from first. Like the people adding comments previously I would suspect the spaces are being put there when you load the textbox up.

Comment: @Dan-o & Jalpesh Vadgama - nearly all of our text is loaded from strings in our DB via a postgres connection, usually accessed through a DataReader. There are a few cases where a multiline textbox is not initalized with a default value by our application, but the same issue occurs - 4 spaces added at the start.
Normal textboxes (single line) are unaffected.

Comment: @CraigMoore - Thats the thing - we can't find out where these spaces are coming from. Using Trim() seems to remove all but the first 4 spaces.

Comment: Please post the code that inserts: Description goes here .  This is obviously not standard textbox or textarea behavior.  I bet your culprit is there as sometimes actual spaces will render in the code, say "   Description goes here". &nbsp is the html tag for space, so if you have those, I'd remove them from in front of the text.  non-obvious JS functions are another common culprit when looking for random text mods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical html textarea (multiline textbox) looks like this:

```
<textarea>This is some content</textarea>
```

Now if your output looks like:

```
<textarea>
    This is some content
</textarea>
```

Then you will introduce your space issue.
When you save this content you gain the 4 spaces at the beginning (the indentation).  Now you load those 4 spaces back and suddenly you have 8 spaces: 4 from the markup and 4 from the saved content.  This pattern continues each time you save the content.

I am unfamiliar with how you (ASP Web Forms) are generating your content, but this should give you a point of investigation.

Comment: And thats what the page source shows (except the closing tag is on the end of the 2nd line. Might try creating a custom multiline textbox control and overriding the Render functions, see if it is a bug in there. Else it may require more time to investigate than what our company can currently spare.

Comment: You can fix it easily in your sql.  `SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Column_Name)) AS Column_Name FROM Table_Name WHERE ....`

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem too. May be mono asp.net bug.

This is my found way, 
build a custom server control to replace multiline textbox.

It's work with asp.net integrated validation framework.

Somebody have better idea?

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
[ControlValueProperty("Text")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
public class TextArea: WebControl, IPostBackDataHandler, IEditableTextControl
{
    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Textarea; }
    }

    public bool CausesValidation
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["CausesValidation"] == null)
                return false;
            return (bool)ViewState["CausesValidation"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["CausesValidation"] = value;
        }
    }

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)ViewState["ValidationGroup"] ?? "";
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ValidationGroup"] = value;
        }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)ViewState["Text"] ?? "";
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Readonly"] == null)
                return false;

            return (bool)ViewState["Readonly"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Readonly"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Rows"] == null)
                return 0;
            return (int)ViewState["Rows"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Rows"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["Columns"] == null)
                return 0;
            return (int)ViewState["Columns"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Columns"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, UniqueID);

        if (Enabled && !IsEnabled)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
        if (ReadOnly)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.ReadOnly, "readonly");

        if (Rows != 0)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rows, Rows.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        if (Columns != 0)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cols, Columns.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));

        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        RenderBeginTag(writer);
        writer.WriteEncodedText(Text);
        RenderEndTag(writer);
    }

    public bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
    {
        var strPostBack = postCollection[postDataKey];
        if (ReadOnly || Text.Equals(strPostBack, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return false;
        Text = strPostBack;
        return true;
    }

    public void RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBackEventControlRegistered)
        {
            Page.AutoPostBackControl = this;
            if (CausesValidation)
                Page.Validate(ValidationGroup);
        }
        TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler TextChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, only got around to testing this just now. First tests prove promising. Will test a bit more, and if everything looks good, I'll mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. To remove extra spaces use textbox_TextChanged event and bind it to textbox.

```
protected void txtDescription_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String strReplace = Regex.Replace(txtDescription.Text.Trim(),@"\t|\n|\r","");
txtDescription.Text = strReplace;
}
```

Bind TextChanged event to textbox:

<asp:TextBox id="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="500" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" OnTextChanged="txtDescription_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

Note: It won't remove the first space, but will work with subsequent spaces of postback.

Answer (score -1):

Your only option is to breakpoint the code and see where they are appearing from.